# Environment that puts its body into a parbox

Tags: environments

I want an environment that creates a tabular inside a `\parbox`. The problem
is how to put delimiters so that the whole thing becomes the second argument to the `\parbox` command.

```
\newenvironment{tabularinparbox}[1]{%
\parbox{\linewidth}
% ... what here ?
\begin{tabular}{#1}
}{%
\end{tabular}
% and here ?
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create an environment as

```
\newenvironment{tabularinparbox}[1]{%
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
       \begin{tabular}{#1}}
    {\end{tabular}%
     \end{minipage}}
```

Using `\parbox` itself won't work without loading some other packages.  That's because you can't have unbalanced brackets in the beginning and ending instructions for `\newenvironment`.  The `minipage` environment does essentially everything that `\parbox` does.

If you're particularly wed to `\parbox` then you can do something like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{tabularinparbox}[1]{%
  \parbox{\linewidth}{%
    \begin{tabular}{#1}
      \BODY
    \end{tabular}%
   }}    
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularinparbox}{llcl}
this & that & a & sdlfkasjdf \\
a & b & asldfkjs d & slk
\end{tabularinparbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution! It cuts the first character of the \BODY in my case though.